# How to determine a view for the polymorphic model in MVC

Tags: oop, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I have a list of entities. Each entity inherits some base class. In the controller I should determine a corresponding view for each entity object. How should I do that?

```
class BaseEntity {}
class FooEntity extends BaseEntity {}
class BarEntity extends BaseEntity {}

class View {}
class FooView extends View {}
class BarView extends View {}
```

Controller code:

```
BaseEntitty entities = repository.getSomeEntities();
List<View> views = new ArrayList();
for(BaseEntity in entities) {
    View view; //How can I determine the concrete view class?
    views.add(view);
}
```

P.S. A proper OOP solution is preferable.

Comment: What about a `ViewFactory` that discriminates using the entity type?

Comment: I should use 'instanceof' operator in the factory, right?

Comment: Depends on the language, but yes, use some way of discriminating by type.

Comment: I've heard about the Visitor pattern and the double dispatch. Is it a good solution for the factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ViewFactory to create the appropriate type view based on the type of `entity`:

```
BaseEntity entities = repository.getSomeEntities();

List<View> views = new ArrayList();

foreach(BaseEntity entity in entities) 
{
    View view = viewFactory.Create(entity);

    views.add(view);
}
```

Comment: As Antony Zh wrote in a comment, the View Factory would end up containing a lot of if and else-if statements to figure out which view one need to instantiate. Feel better if polymorphism could be used instead, but one don't want to make the Models messy by adding a `getView()` method to them. Is there really no better solution?

Comment: It's a good point. I think there are a number of ways around the `if-else` approach. You could use an IoC-type approach where appropriate types are registered or dynamically discovered with their view type and then the factory just has to find the type. I suppose to entity itself could know which view is appropriate, which leans more on the polymorphic approach, but UI concerns start to leak into areas that might not be desirable.

Comment: I wonder if partial classes could be a good solution. Then the UI part of the app could add a `getView()` method to all model classes indicating which View that should be used to visualize them, and the business part of the app with the models would remain just containing business logic.